# Python scientific notation using D instead of E

Tags: python, locale, scientific-notation

Some results file produced by Fortran programs report double precision numbers (in scientific notation) using the letter `D` instead of `E`, for instance:

```
1.2345D+02
# instead of
1.2345E+02
```

I need to process huge amounts of this data using Python, and I just realized it cannot read the numbers in the `D` notation, for instance:

```
>>> A = 1.0D+01
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    A = 1.0D+01
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Can I change my locale and let Python know that `D` means `E`? I really would not want to make a global search-and-replace!

Comment: I guess modifying your Fortran programs is not an option ?

Comment: @HP Mark: not an option.

Comment: I'd use sed to rip through the file and write it into the format your Python program wants.  But then, I'd use sed for most programs anyway :-)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The simplest way, from your Python program, would be just to add a step before you interpret each entry:

```
>>> val = "1.5698D+03"  # 1,569.8
>>> print float(val.replace('D', 'E'))
1569.8
```

Comment: I will accept this as the answer, but I'm sad Python does not have a better way to do this. Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

If you are dealing with lots of data and/or are doing a lot computations with that data, you might consider using the fortran-friendly [numpy](https://numpy.org/) module which supports double-precision fortran format out of the box.

```
>>> numpy.float('1.5698D+03')
1569.8
```

Comment: I've been putting off numpy for a long time... maybe it's time I reconsider. Thank you! (+1)

Comment: On older versions of NumPy (e.g., 1.3.0) this raises a ValueError. I'm not sure what version of NumPy this was introduced.

Comment: numpy version 1.80 still doesn't support this. Exactly what version of numpy was this?

Comment: This appears to work only on older versions of Python on certain platforms.  It doesn't work for Windows 7 64-bit/Python 2.7.9/numpy 1.9.2.  See http://bugs.python.org/issue7919 .

Comment: It doesn't work for numpy version 1.15.3 (most recent as of 2018), either.

Answer (score 8):

Another option is the [fortranformat](https://web.archive.org/web/20200621211925/https://bitbucket.org/brendanarnold/py-fortranformat/wiki/Home) library for Python. It will read strings and interpret them according to a FORTRAN format statement. i.e.

```
>>> import fortranformat as ff
>>> line = ff.FortranRecordReader('(F10.0)')
>>> line.read('1.5698D+03')
[1569.8]
```

Install with `easy_install -U fortranformat`

Any questions, email me (I'm the author).