# Reading fortran double precision format into python

Tags: python, input, double, fortran

I am trying to read a Fortran double-precision number like 1.2345D+02 into python, but I got the following error:

```
>>> float('1.2345D+02')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 1.2345D+02
```

By following the advice on [Python scientific notation using D instead of E](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1959210/python-scientific-notation-using-d-instead-of-e), I tried numpy but I also get the same error:

```
import numpy
>>> numpy.float("1.2345D+02")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 1.2345D+02
```

Is there a solution in Python to read those double precision numbers without just changing the 'D' to 'E'?

EDIT: I replaced a bad syntax on the strings. But still I get errors.

Comment: Just a heads up that maybe the `fortranformat` Python library (on PyPI) can help - I should probably disclose that I'm the author.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What's wrong with `float(str.replace("D", "E"))`?

Please note, numpy DOES support fortran notation: `numpy.float("1.2345D+02")`.

You seem to have some *deeper purpose*, perhaps shedding light on it would help.

Comment: In general, nothing is wrong with replacing "D" with "E". I just want to know if there is a "native" solution. If numpy supports fortran notation, why is it failing as shown in the example?
Yes, I need to parse some huge fortran-generated data files and to extract some particular data. Thanks!

Comment: Because `numpy.float(1.2345D+02)` would be parsed by the python interpreter as a call to `numpy.float` with `1.2345D+02`. `1.2345D+02` is unknown to the python interpreter so it gives an error. `"1.2345D+02"` is a string, which is perfectly fine.

Comment: Thanks. Actually it was a typo on my example. I already corrected it but the error (another one) remains.

Comment: Possibly you are using different versions of numpy

Comment: At least `numpy 1.5.1` *doesn't* support `numpy.float("1.2345D+02")`.

Comment: Use f2py to create .pyd file. Run it from Python. When Fortran send a double precision number to Python, Python will accept it without the `D`. But, if you already have the fortran-generated data files, perhaps you can use the solution by @nightcracker.

Comment: Thanks, @J.F. Sebastian , I have numpy 1.5.1 and that is the reason.

Comment: you also need to be careful that some Fortran compilers will print numbers larger than 1.e99 dropping the "E", so you'll get 0.1+100 which is 10**99 python doesn't like this format either.

Comment: The first option is great; thanks. This could be made generic by using `float(re.sub('[dD]', 'e', str))` instead. Somehow, it seems that recent versions of numpy has stopped support for the fortran notation. (I am using numpy v1.17.4.)

Answer (score 1):

The substitution can be made a bit more careful by using a regular expression:

```
import re
re_dbl_fort = re.compile(r'(\d*\.\d+)[dD]([-+]?\d+)')

text = 'DEW=[0.242D+03 -4.320D-06]'
re_dbl_fort.sub(r'\1E\2', text)
# DEW=[0.242E+03 -4.320E-06]
```

Or if you have a list of strings (lines) read from a file using `readlines()`:

```
lines = ['REPORT CARD\n', 'GRADE: D+ (1.3D+00/4.0D+00)\n']
for ln, line in enumerate(lines):
    res = re_dbl_fort.sub(r'\1E\2', line)
    if line != res:
        lines[ln] = res
# ['REPORT CARD\n', 'GRADE: D+ (1.3E+00/4.0E+00)\n']
```