# Read Fortran complex number into Python

Tags: python, numpy, fortran

I'm trying to read a file (generated with Fortran) with complex numbers into Python.

Say, after using `a = f1.readline().split( )`, I get the following value for `a`:

```
a = ['(4.471719725275173E-003,2.163649191486555E-002)']
```

If I do

```
b = np.complex(a[0])
```

it produces an error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-cff25069e279> in <module>()
----> 1 b = np.complex(a[0])

ValueError: complex() arg is a malformed string
```

I tried to do this based on the fact that `numpy` seems to support Fortran notation ([Reading fortran double precision format into python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5989351/reading-fortran-double-precision-format-into-python)). Is there an equivalent function for complex numbers?

If not, what would be the best way to proceed (rather than using different delimiters in the `split( )` call and reconstruct the complex number by hand).

Comment: Please never use "It doesn't work." in your questions. Describe what it actually does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can parse it this way (https://stackoverflow.com/a/9763133/721644):

```
from ast import literal_eval

t = literal_eval(a[0])

b = complex(t[0], t[1])

>(0.004471719725275173+0.02163649191486555j)
```

It first makes a tuple of floats and than uses its components as arguments to `complex()`.

Comment: Thank you! Simple and effective.

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np
a = ['(4.471719725275173E-003,2.163649191486555E-002)']
i, j = np.safe_eval(a[0])

print(np.complex(i, j))
(0.004471719725275173+0.02163649191486555j)
```

If you are reading from a file and want an array:

```
import numpy as np



def to_complex(f):
    conv = lambda x: np.complex(*np.safe_eval(x))
    return np.genfromtxt(f, converters={0: conv})
```

Output:

```
In [3]: cat out.txt
(4.471719725275173E-003,2.163649191486555E-002)
(6.471719725275173E-003,2.163649191486555E-002)
In [4]: print(to_complex("out.txt"))
[ 0.00447172+0.02163649j  0.00647172+0.02163649j]
```

Or if you just want a value at a time:

```
from itertools import imap
def to_complex(f):
    with open(f) as fle:
        for a, b in imap(np.safe_eval, fle):
            yield np.complex(a, b)
```

Output:

```
In [7]: print(list(to_complex("out.txt")))
[(0.004471719725275173+0.02163649191486555j), (0.006471719725275173+0.02163649191486555j)]
```

You could also just cast the data yourself stripping and splitting which would be faster than using safe_eval:

```
from itertools import imap

def to_complex(f):
    with open(f) as fle:
        for tup in imap(str.strip, fle):
            yield np.complex(*map(float, tup.strip("()").split(",")))
```

You can use the same logic in with `genfromtxt`:

from itertools import imap

```
def to_complex(f):
    conv = lambda x: np.complex(*imap(float, x.strip("()").split(",")))
    return np.genfromtxt(f, converters={0: conv})
```