# How to read a file with fortran formatted numbers into python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, fortran, genfromtxt

I have a fortran formatted txt file with numbers like this `0.755473D-08`.

if I use `np.genfromtxt(data,dtype=None)`, it shows `b'0.755473D-08'`. How can I can I get rid of `b`?

Comment: Did you search before asking?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5989351/reading-fortran-double-precision-format-into-python Combine with `converters` in `genfromtxt`.

Comment: And this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1959210/python-scientific-notation-using-d-instead-of-e

Comment: Yes, but my problem is I cannot load the fortran formatted numbers into python because it shows `nan`, not unable to replace `D`.

Comment: this seems to be specifically about using `genfromtxt` ?  Off hand I'd say you need to set the type to string and convert after reading.

Comment: The `b'...'` denotes a bytestring in py3.  If you change the 'D' to 'e' ordinary float parsing should work.

Comment: @hpaulj I'm a newbie about bytestring, how exactly I should do? I tried `data.replace("D","e")`, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

```
In [315]: txt = '''0.755473D-08
     ...: 0.755473D-08
     ...: 0.755473D-08'''
In [316]: np.genfromtxt(txt.splitlines())
Out[316]: array([nan, nan, nan])
In [317]: np.genfromtxt(txt.splitlines(),dtype=None)
...
Out[317]: array([b'0.755473D-08', b'0.755473D-08', b'0.755473D-08'], dtype='|S12')
```

Using String `replace`:

```
In [319]: txt.replace('D','e')
Out[319]: '0.755473e-08\n0.755473e-08\n0.755473e-08'
In [320]: np.genfromtxt(_.splitlines())
Out[320]: array([7.55473e-09, 7.55473e-09, 7.55473e-09])
```

That could also be done line by line (when reading from a file).

With a converter, applied to each element (column per line):

```
In [326]: np.genfromtxt(txt.splitlines(), converters={0:lambda x:float(x.replace('D','e'))}, encoding=None)
Out[326]: array([7.55473e-09, 7.55473e-09, 7.55473e-09])
```

It doesn't try to do any further `dtype` conversion after the converter, so I had to include the `float()` in the converter.