# Python: trouble reading number format

Tags: python, string-formatting

I am reading from a file where numbers are listed as -4.8416932597054D-04, where D is scientific notation.  I have never seen this notation before.  How can Python read -4.8416932597054***D***-04 as -4.8416932597054***E***-04  I've looked at other question and haven't read anything that addresses this?  (Or I have and didn't recognize it.)  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
def to_float(s):
    return float(s.lower().replace('d', 'e'))
```

**Edit:** Can you give an example of an input string that still gives you 'the same error'? Because `to_float('-4.8416932597054D-04')` works perfectly for me, returning `-0.00048416932597054`.

Comment: I'm still getting the same error.  I just found other discussions identify D as FORTRAN scientific notation and numpy as FORTRAN-friendly.  I've already imported numpy for other purposes, so perhaps there is a way there.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1959210/python-scientific-notation-using-d-instead-of-e

Comment: Sorry, I initially did it wrong.  I'm getting  "'int' object has no attribute 'lower'"

Comment: I should also add that I will use the function to read elements in an array.  For example,  to_float(col_C), col_C being a 1D array read from a text file.

Comment: @user3052914: so don't pass it an int! Read a string from the file, pass it to to_float, and get back a float value.

Comment: def to_float(s):
----> 2     return float(s.lower().replace('d', 'e'))
      3 
      4 col_C='-4.8416932597054D-04'
      5 

ValueError: could not convert string to float: col_c

Comment: Pardon the last comment.  I got a ValueError: could not convert string to float.  I need to go back to where I read in these column and format them as strings; then it should work.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Do **you** understand this notation? If so, **you** can use your knowledge to solve that. Do string formatting with the number, parse it, extract `D-04` from the number using regular expressions and translate it into a more numberish string, append to the original string and make Python convert it.

There's not a Python module for every case or every data model in the world, we (you, especially) have to create your own solutions.

---

#### Example:

```
def read_strange_notation(strange_number):
    number, notation = strange_number.split('D-')
    number, notation = int(number), int(notation)
    actual_number = number ** notation # here I don't know what `D-` means, 
                                       # so you do something with these parts
    return actual_number
```

Comment: I do understand the notation- now.  I, however, do not know how to parse, extract, translate and append it.  Could you help me with that?